# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method Fixed(I)Landroidx/constraintlayout/core/state/Dimension (Compose Constraint Layout)

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-constraintlayout

I am using compose views inside fragments and designing my some views with compose constraint layout. I am getting issue with Dimension static methods from constraint layout.

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method Fixed(I)Landroidx/constraintlayout/core/state/Dimension; in class Landroidx/constraintlayout/core/state/Dimension; or its super classes (declaration of 'androidx.constraintlayout.core.state.Dimension' appears in /data/app/~~yLRuZH8qVj40vxjmzszxBw==/world.finds.app.android.debug-VK6fWa83-bLiaaL1CCDHuA==/base.apk!classes26.dex)
at androidx.constraintlayout.compose.Measurer.performMeasure-DjhGOtQ(ConstraintLayout.kt:1201)
at androidx.constraintlayout.compose.ConstraintLayoutKt$rememberConstraintLayoutMeasurePolicy$1$measurePolicy$1.measure-3p2s80s(ConstraintLayout.kt:110)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerNodeCoordinator.measure-BRTryo0(InnerNodeCoordinator.kt:103)
at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.PaddingModifier.measure-3p2s80s(Padding.kt:364)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.BackwardsCompatNode.measure-3p2s80s(BackwardsCompatNode.kt:319)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:155)
at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.FillModifier.measure-3p2s80s(Size.kt:658)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.BackwardsCompatNode.measure-3p2s80s(BackwardsCompatNode.kt:319)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:155)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$performMeasure$2.invoke(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:1090)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$performMeasure$2.invoke(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:1086)
at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:2139)
at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$observeReads$1$1.invoke(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:234)
at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$observeReads$1$1.invoke(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:230)
at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt__DerivedStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(DerivedState.kt:341)
at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(Unknown Source:1)
at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:230)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:120)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeMeasureSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:107)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.performMeasure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:1086)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.access$performMeasure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:36)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate.remeasure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:342)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:321)
at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.LazyLayoutMeasureScopeImpl.measure-0kLqBqw(LazyLayoutMeasureScope.kt:120)
at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyMeasuredItemProvider.getAndMeasure-ZjPyQlc(LazyMeasuredItemProvider.kt:47)
at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyListMeasureKt.measureLazyList-QaF8Ofo(LazyListMeasure.kt:159)
at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyListKt$rememberLazyListMeasurePolicy$1$1.invoke-0kLqBqw(LazyList.kt:299)
at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyListKt$rememberLazyListMeasurePolicy$1$1.invoke(LazyList.kt:190)
at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.LazyLayoutKt$LazyLayout$1$2$1.invoke-0kLqBqw(LazyLayout.kt:71)
at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.LazyLayoutKt$LazyLayout$1$2$1.invoke(LazyLayout.kt:69)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutNodeSubcompositionsState$createMeasurePolicy$1.measure-3p2s80s(SubcomposeLayout.kt:591)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerNodeCoordinator.measure-BRTryo0(InnerNodeCoordinator.kt:103)
2023-02-21 14:10:26.619 13004-13004 AndroidRuntime          world.finds.app.android.debug        E      at androidx.compose.foundation.AndroidOverscrollKt$StretchOverscrollNonClippingLayer$2.invoke-3p2s80s(AndroidOverscroll.kt:534)
at androidx.compose.foundation.AndroidOverscrollKt$StretchOverscrollNonClippingLayer$2.invoke(AndroidOverscroll.kt:533)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutModifierImpl.measure-3p2s80s(LayoutModifier.kt:285)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.BackwardsCompatNode.measure-3p2s80s(BackwardsCompatNode.kt:319)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:155)
at androidx.compose.foundation.AndroidOverscrollKt$StretchOverscrollNonClippingLayer$1.invoke-3p2s80s(AndroidOverscroll.kt:518)
at androidx.compose.foundation.AndroidOverscrollKt$StretchOverscrollNonClippingLayer$1.invoke(AndroidOverscroll.kt:517)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutModifierImpl.measure-3p2s80s(LayoutModifier.kt:285)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.BackwardsCompatNode.measure-3p2s80s(BackwardsCompatNode.kt:319)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:155)
at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.SimpleGraphicsLayerModifier.measure-3p2s80s(GraphicsLayerModifier.kt:673)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:155)
at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.FillModifier.measure-3p2s80s(Size.kt:658)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.BackwardsCompatNode.measure-3p2s80s(BackwardsCompatNode.kt:319)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:155)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$performMeasure$2.invoke(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:1090)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$performMeasure$2.invoke(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:1086)
at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:2139)
at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$observeReads$1$1.invoke(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:234)
at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$observeReads$1$1.invoke(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:230)
at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt__DerivedStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(DerivedState.kt:341)
at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(Unknown Source:1)
at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:230)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:120)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeMeasureSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:107)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.performMeasure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:1086)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.access$performMeasure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:36)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate.remeasure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:342)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.remeasure-_Sx5XlM$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:1166)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.remeasure-_Sx5XlM$ui_release$default(LayoutNode.kt:1157)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.doRemeasure-sdFAvZA(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:309)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.remeasureAndRelayoutIfNeeded(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:434)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.access$remeasureAndRelayoutIfNeeded(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:39)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.measureAndLayout(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:330)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.measureAndLayout(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:778)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.Owner.measureAndLayout$default(Owner.kt:216)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.dispatchDraw(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:1008)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:23197)
2023-02-21 14:10:26.620 13004-13004 AndroidRuntime          world.finds.app.android.debug        E      at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22061)
at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4513)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4486)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22017)
at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4513)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4486)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22017)
at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4513)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4486)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22017)
at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4513)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4486)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22017)
at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4513)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4486)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22017)
at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4513)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4486)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22017)
at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4513)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4486)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22017)
at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4513)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4486)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22017)
at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4513)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4486)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22017)
at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:689)
at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:695)
at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:793)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:4670)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:4381)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:3600)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2328)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:9087)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1231)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1239)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:899)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:832)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1214)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)

> Kotlin Version: 1.8.0
>
> Compose compiler version: 1.4.0
>
> Compose version: 1.3.3
>
> Compose Constraint layout version: 1.0.1

And this is usage from **fragment**

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class ActivityFragment: Fragment() {

    private val viewModel: ActivityViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        return ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
            // Dispose of the Composition when the view's LifecycleOwner
            // is destroyed
            setViewCompositionStrategy(ViewCompositionStrategy.DisposeOnViewTreeLifecycleDestroyed)
            setContent {
                Activity(viewModel = viewModel)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have the gradle dependency for ```androidx.coinstraintlayout.core``` ?

Take a look here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.constraintlayout/constraintlayout-core/1.1.0-alpha07

Answer (score 0):

Recently encountered a similar problem.
There were multiple versions of androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout library including 2.2.0-alpha03.
Fixed this error with changing to stable 2.1.4 version.